# Jackson's readEntity is serializing my Exceptions into java.lang.Throwable instead of the correct Error exception

Tags: java, rest, serialization, jackson, jersey

In my code I have an Exception that extends IllegalArgumentException:

```
public class InvalidDataSourceException extends IllegalArgumentException {
  public InvalidDataSourceException(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
  }
}
```

And in my Jersey REST web service, all errors are wrapped with a class `RESTError` so that
all rest services can throw this same exception:

```
public class RESTError extends Throwable {
    public RESTError(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

So when the InvalidDataSourceException occurs, it is thrown as the cause of a `RESTError`:

```
throw new RESTError(invalidDataSourceException);
```

We have registered a serializer for Throwable object:

```
public class ThrowableSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Throwable> {

  @Override
  public void serialize(Throwable value, JsonGenerator jgen,
      SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    jgen.writeStartObject();
    jgen.writeStringField("class", value.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    jgen.writeStringField("message", value.getMessage());
    jgen.writeObjectField("stackTrace", value.getStackTrace());
    jgen.writeStringField("stackTraceAsString", Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(value));
    jgen.writeObjectField("cause", value.getCause());
    jgen.writeEndObject();

  }
}
```

Below is a unit test, in which I attempt to write the RESTError to string, then re-serialize:

```
public class TestJsonSerializationOfExceptions {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestJsonSerializationOfExceptions.class);

  @Test
  public void testBasic() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = ObjectMapperFactory.create();
    try {
      throw new InvalidDataSourceException("test msg");
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      RESTError restError = new RESTError(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, Errors.General, t);
      String str = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(restError); // It is correct here!
      log.info("Rest error when serialized: {}", str);
      restError = objectMapper.readValue(str, RESTError.class);
      Assert.assertEquals(restError.getCause().getClass(), InvalidDataSourceException.class);
    }
  }
}
```

When I do this, the Exception cause is serialized to `java.lang.Throwable`, instead of my custom `InvalidDataSourceException`. It down-casted it. Thus the unit test fails. Why is that?

Comment: Well first of all, is that another Java app aware of existence class InvalidDataSourceException?

Comment: Hi @JamesCube thanks so much for response. I added a Unit Test that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Ok, now it makes more sense. You have serializer that puts info about class to json, very good. But, shouldn't you have a symmetric deserializer? [Something extending from that](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html). With no straight mapping those are just fields, and Jackson by default just ignores fields it doesn't know about (as far as I remember, might be wrong now).

Comment: You need a unmarshaller that understands your custom throwable JSON. What's the point of all this anyway?

Comment: I tried that. And i realized that there is built-in Exception throwable deserializer overriding my custom deserializer and that is doing something that isn't correct. I have a `@class` and it just ignored it. After that I gave up and started using error codes being returned from the main error object so that I can avoid the issue all together. disappointing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) javadoc.

When you extend Throwable and pass another one to constructor, it is passed to `private Throwable cause` property. And then this is the only information about type. So during deserialization Java only knows that there is property `cause` with a type `Throwable` and has no information if it was `InvalidDataSourceException` or whatever else.

EDIT: Now it looks like missing deserializer issue

Comment: We have a Throwable serializer. Sorry I forgot to mention that. I updated the ticket with that.

Comment: i changed the ticket references from "jersey" to "jackson" because jersey had nothing to do with it. i also added a unit test.